# Error en captura de datos en DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En un `Form` introduje un `DataGridView`, con 4 columnas, lleno cada celda con información (Texto) y cada vez que doy <kbd>Enter</kbd>, se genera una nueva linea que debe llenarse, el problema es que si no doy <kbd>Enter</kbd>, no se captura el dato de la ultima columna o celda y el compilador lo toma como `null`, mi pregunta es:

¿Como obtener los datos o el dato aun cuando no se cumpla la condición del <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: el "llenado" que mencionas es manual? Entiendo que si ingresas un valor en la celda y sacar el foco deberia terminar la edicion y tomarte el valor, quneu no se si eso creara una nueva row

Comment: Efectivamente el "llenado" de cada celda es manual. Ingreso el dato y paso a la siguiente celda, cuando he terminado de llenar esa fila, doy Enter y se genera la siguiente, hasta ese punto no hay problema, pero si lleno cada celda de la fila y no doy Enter en la celda final, me arroja una excepción, pues Toma como Null esa ultima celda.

Comment: Deberías de poner el código que has escrito para ver tu lógica y descifrar el error.

Comment: No sé si estás utilizando los controles nativos de WinForms o alguno de terceros, pero probablemente debas usar el event `Validating` y/o `Validated`